# Migrate from .Net from 4.6 to .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

I want to migrate my code .Netframework 4.6.2 to .Netcore 3.1 .I read many documentation  but not able achieve my goal .I do not want manually copy paste from .Netframework to .Netcore .

so ,If can guide me what step i have follow in VS2019???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

In place of this their may be thousand line of code

Comment: What kind of code? What problems did you have when moving the code to Core?

Comment: This is going to depend heavily on your project. Migrating e.g. a console app is going to be wildly different than migrating an ASP.NET Web Forms app.

Comment: Your converion depend upon the code .I want what are step that we have to follow to convert .Netframe to .Netcore .and do not want maually copy paste

Answer (score 3):

You can read this post from Microsoft.

[Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/).

You may find the tools listed in this article helpful when porting:

[NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) - A toolchain that can generate a report of how portable your code is between .NET Framework and .NET Core:

- As a [command-line tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport/releases)
- As a [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer)

[.NET API analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer) - A Roslyn analyzer that discovers potential compatibility risks for C# APIs on different platforms and detects calls to deprecated APIs.

[try-convert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/try-convert/) - A .NET Core global tool that can convert a project or entire solution to the .NET SDK, including moving desktop apps to .NET Core. It is not recommended if you have a more complicated build established (such as custom tasks, targets, or imports), and it rejects many project types that are incompatible with .NET Core.

Comment: i read this but do not get much from it .if you can please help me  i am using vs2019

Comment: @JaiMahesh You can read more about these tools and how to use them.